# How can I display correctly PDF in Chrome without its internal PDF viewer?

Tags: oracle, google-chrome, pdf, report, barcode

I am using IDAHC39M Code 39 Barcode in Oracle Report Builder 11.1.2.2.0, to show a barcode on a pdf. This PDF is in a PL SQL package using iframe.

It is displayed on a webpage, the PDF is opening in Acrobat. The iframe is pointing to the same domain: src="https:// www. test .ro / reports / rwservlet?test & report=p_form_test.rdf & p_id='||p_id||'&p_session='||p_session||' & destype=cache & desformat=pdf"

When I use Chrome, without adding its internal PDF viewer, the barcode only displays the number behind. I want all users to see the barcode correctly and not force them to add PDF viewer to thier browser. How can I do that?

Thank you kindly!

Comment: Is the PDF being displayed in the IE and Firefox browser, or opening in Acrobat?  There is a new flag in Chrome (but I think disabled by default for now) to use a new internal PDF viewer.

Comment: Thank you very much! It was because of the PDF Viewer not being added in Chrome. The PDF is opening in Acrobat. But, how do I resolve for other users? I want everybody to see it correctly, not just me. Thank you!

Comment: You may be hitting a slightly different issue (also): Is the `iframe` pointing to the same domain?  If not, that could be another cause.  Not sure what flags, etc. to use to ease things for other users.

Comment: Yes, the iframe is pointing to the same domain: src="https://www.test.ro/reports/rwservlet?test&report=p_form_test.rdf&p_id='||p_id||'&p_session='||p_session||'&destype=cache&desformat=pdf" . I am thinking to open the pdf report in a new tab with Edge, but I don't know if it's possible. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the details.  I'm out of ideas. If you [edit] your question, and add the information to your question that the `iframe` is pointing to the same domain, and add the tag [pdf] to bring attention to the PDF handling question.

Comment: Thank you so much, I did that. At least, now I know what the problem is.